# Add additional items to jquery geocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, geocomplete

Is it possible to add additional items to jquery geocomplete list?
http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/
I use geocomplete jquery plugin in my search form which enable the users to search hotel by address. But I want in this autocomplete service to appear hotel names too because someone can try to search by hotel name. I want one smart input. Is there a way to add a list of hotel names with their geocoordinates to the autocomplete list?